# Windows Azure Virtual machine performance

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I am trying to migrate my applications from GoDaddy virtual machine to Azure Virtual machine.

I want to have 1 VM as a database server and another VM as webserver, but it works extremely slow in that case, I installed DB on the same server as web application and it's fast.

So the question: How can I increase performance between two virtual machines? Both are located in "East US", is it some way to may be locate both in the same box...? 
What can you suggest?

Comment: which VM sizes did you chosse? What kind of applications are you hosting? It looks like network latency (should not be much of an issue if you are in the same region/data center) and/or bandwidth seems to hurt you.

Comment: Call to SQL on the same machine is always going to be faster (one it does not need to serialize to network calls) especially if it is chatty.  But you should not see big differences.

Comment: I use small instances for both DB and WEB server. But looks like size of VM does not matter, I tried with extra small and large, and it's the same. Application is wordpress blog and database is MySQL

Comment: The difference is very big, instead of loading page in about 1 second when all located in the same machine, I have about 10-15 seconds when it's two separate machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue. It's not Azure, it's problem with MySQL database.
I have to set parameter

```
skip-name-resolve
```

in my.ini file, and not it's as fast as when both located on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the VM's in the same affinity group so the machines are geolocated together by the Fabric Controller i.e. in East US

Machines in the sames Cloud Service and affinity group should have lightening direct network traffic, can you run some ping tests between them on the same affinity group and share with us plz.

e.g. RDP in and run ping from the command line.

As stated above the beefer the machines the better the bandwidth/network traffic, scaling up the SQL machine is advisable.

*More on Affinity Groups here: http://convective.wordpress.com/2012/06/10/affinity-groups-in-windows-azure/

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Affinity Group is the way to go. Configure both VM in the same affinity group will co-locate those two VMs.